# Solution of modified Laplacian Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have derived the following fourth order PDE for my research problem

$$
\widehat{\nabla} ^{2}\widehat{\nabla} ^{2} w+ \alpha \widehat{\nabla} ^{2}w  + 
\beta w = 0.
$$
where $\widehat{\nabla} ^{2}$ is a modified Laplacian given by
$\widehat{\nabla} ^{2} = \left(\dfrac{\partial^{2} }{\partial r^{2}} + \dfrac{1}{(r-R_{1})}\dfrac{\partial }{\partial r} + \dfrac{1}{(r-R_{1})^{2}}\dfrac{\partial^{2} }{\partial \theta^{2}}
\right),$

and $w= w(r,\theta)$ and $\alpha,  \beta$ are constants.

The above PDE shall be factored as $\left( \widehat{\nabla} ^{2} + \lambda_{1} \right)\left( \widehat{\nabla} ^{2} + \lambda_{2} \right)w = 0$

where $ \lambda_{j} = \xi_{1} + (-1)^{j} \sqrt{\xi_{1}\strut^{2} + \xi_{2}}$,

$\xi_{1} = \dfrac{1}{2}\alpha$, and $\xi_{1} = \beta$.

The domain of the problem is an annular circular disc with inner and outer radius as $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$.

$R_{1} \leq r \leq R_{2} $ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi $.

The boundary conditions at the inner boundary are given by
$$w(R_{1}, \theta) = 0,\\ \dfrac{\partial w(R_{1},\theta)}{\partial r} = \dfrac{\partial w(R_{1},\theta)}{\partial \theta} = 0,\\
\dfrac{\partial^{2}w(R_{1}, \theta) }{\partial r^{2}} = \dfrac{\partial^{2}w(R_{1}, \theta) }{\partial \theta^{2}}=0,\\
\dfrac{\partial^{3}w(R_{1}, \theta) }{\partial r^{3}} = \dfrac{\partial^{3}w(R_{1}, \theta) }{\partial \theta^{3}}=0. $$

The fourth-order differential equation shall be alternatively written as two second order PDEs as

$$
\left( \widehat{\nabla} ^{2} + \lambda_{i} \right)w = \overline{w}, \quad \left( \widehat{\nabla} ^{2} + \lambda_{j} \right)\overline{w} = 0
$$
where if $i = 1$ then $j = 2$ and vice versa.

Could anyone please suggest on how to obtain the final solution of $w(r,\theta)$ solving the above two PDEs ? Thank you so much.

Comment: (1) Why not just map $r\leftrightarrow r-R_1$ and use a punctured disc and reduce to usual Laplacian? (2) Since $(\nabla^2+\lambda)_\lambda$ is obviously a commuting family, you can just solve $(\nabla^2+\lambda_i)w=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It sounds great. Could you please give me any hint on solving $( \nabla^{2} + \lambda_{i})w = 0$ I only know how to solve $ \nabla^{2} w= 0$. This extra $ +  \lambda_{i}w$ is something I don't know how to solve.

Comment: @Bharath The extra $+ \lambda_{1} w$ term makes your problem the [Helmholtz equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation) and is amenable to separation of variables.